# How to enable an option and then append a value to the option?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to develop a couple of playbooks that will enable an option (if it has been disabled) and then append a username to the option.
i.e.

That is - go from:

> #HideUsers

To:

> #HideUsers
>
> HideUsers=frodo,sam

I get the following when trying the (almost) identical playbooks below:

> #HideUsers
>
> HideUsers=sam
>
> HideUsers=frodo,sam

The playbooks:

*Test playbook 1:*

```yaml
---
  - name: "Test playbook 1."
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - name: "Set the user to be added"
        set_fact:
          username: "frodo"

      - name: "Add {{ username }} to HideUsers option - if HideUsers has been enabled."
        lineinfile:
          path: "files/sddm.conf"
          regexp: "^HideUsers=((?!.*{{ item }}.*$).*$)"  # checks that username is not in HideUsers 
          backrefs: True
          line: 'HideUsers=\1,{{ item }}'
        loop:
          - "{{ username }}"
 
      - name: "Enable HideUsers option if it is disabled."
        lineinfile:
          path: "files/sddm.conf"
          insertafter: '^#HideUsers=$'
          line: "HideUsers={{ username }}"
```

*Test playbook 2:*

```yaml
---
  - name: "Test playbook 2."
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - name: "Set the user to be added"
        set_fact:
          username: "sam"

      - name: "Add {{ username }} to HideUsers option - if HideUsers has been enabled."
        lineinfile:
          path: "files/sddm.conf"
          regexp: "^HideUsers=((?!.*{{ item }}.*$).*$)"  # checks that username is not in HideUsers 
          backrefs: True
          line: 'HideUsers=\1,{{ item }}'
        loop:
          - "{{ username }}"
 
      - name: "Enable HideUsers option if it is disabled."
        lineinfile:
          path: "files/sddm.conf"
          insertafter: '^#HideUsers=$'
          line: "HideUsers={{ username }}"
```

Whilst I can see the issue I cannot see how to get exactly what I want. Presumably I could do it by shell-ing out but if there a way to do it solely in Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not (at least not easily) doable with `lineinfile` alone. Here's a complete minimal example using a regex_search and a replacement.

Project structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── my_file.ini
└── test.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

I used a `my_file.ini` a bit closer to a real world content to make sure test were coherent. This is the file before running anything

```
$ cat my_file.ini 
SomeParameter1=1
#SomeOtherParam
#HideUsers
#SomeParameter2=toto
YetAnotherParam=veryimportant
```

The following `test.yml` playbook should be self explainatory and contains intermediate debugging for clarity

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    config_file: "my_file.ini"
    user_regex: '^#* *HideUsers=?(?P<users>.*)$'
    # This is a list of found matches
    users_matched_raw: "{{ _config.content | b64decode | regex_search(user_regex, '\\g<users>', multiline=true) }}"
    # We extract first match in list, split it on comma and remove any empty elements
    users_matched_list: "{{ users_matched_raw | first | split(',') | map('trim') | select }}"
    # The full list merges extracted + additional. We sort and make it unique to
    # avoid redundant users and avoid changing the file for same users in different order.
    full_user_list: "{{ (users_matched_list + (additional_users | d([]))) | sort | unique }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure additional_users is a list or undefined
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: additional_users | d([]) | type_debug == "list"
        msg: Please provide additional_users as a list

    - name: Perform changes on config file if needed
      when: additional_users | d([]) | length > 0
      block:
        - name: Get the ini file content
          ansible.builtin.slurp:
            src: "{{ config_file }}"
          register: _config

        - name: Show the raw captured string
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            var: users_matched_raw

        - name: Show the calculated captured user list
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            var: users_matched_list

        - name: Show the merged list of users (captured + additional)
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            var: full_user_list

        - name: Replace the line if needed with merged list of users
          ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
            dest: "{{ config_file }}"
            regex: "{{ user_regex }}"
            line: "HideUsers={{ full_user_list | join(',') }}"
```

Let's run this a first time with some new users:

```
$ ansible-playbook -e '{"additional_users":["sam","john"]}' test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Make sure additional_users is a list or undefined] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [Get the ini file content] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show the raw captured string] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users_matched_raw": [
        ""
    ]
}

TASK [Show the calculated captured user list] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users_matched_list": []
}

TASK [Show the merged list of users (captured + additional)] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "full_user_list": [
        "john",
        "sam"
    ]
}

TASK [Replace the line if needed with merged list of users] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

We can see the file has been changed as expected

```
$ cat my_file.ini 
SomeParameter1=1
#SomeOtherParam
HideUsers=john,sam
#SomeParameter2=toto
YetAnotherParam=veryimportant
```

We can run the file a second time with more users (note that the existing ones are not duplicated)

```
$ ansible-playbook -e '{"additional_users":["jack","john"]}' test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Make sure additional_users is a list or undefined] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [Get the ini file content] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show the raw captured string] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users_matched_raw": [
        "john,sam"
    ]
}

TASK [Show the calculated captured user list] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users_matched_list": [
        "john",
        "sam"
    ]
}

TASK [Show the merged list of users (captured + additional)] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "full_user_list": [
        "jack",
        "john",
        "sam"
    ]
}

TASK [Replace the line if needed with merged list of users] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ cat my_file.ini 
SomeParameter1=1
#SomeOtherParam
HideUsers=jack,john,sam
#SomeParameter2=toto
YetAnotherParam=veryimportant
```

As a non exhaustive last example, we can run again with only existing users in any order and check idempotence is fullfilled (no change)

```
$ ansible-playbook -e '{"additional_users":["sam","jack","john"]}' test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Make sure additional_users is a list or undefined] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [Get the ini file content] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show the raw captured string] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users_matched_raw": [
        "jack,john,sam"
    ]
}

TASK [Show the calculated captured user list] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users_matched_list": [
        "jack",
        "john",
        "sam"
    ]
}

TASK [Show the merged list of users (captured + additional)] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "full_user_list": [
        "jack",
        "john",
        "sam"
    ]
}

TASK [Replace the line if needed with merged list of users] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you. That's brilliant as I never would have thought doing it that way.

Is there any way of preserving the initial line (i.e. #HideUsers) without overridding it?

Comment: Yes, change the regex so that it only matches the expected enabled line and add `insert_after: #HideUsers` option in your `lineinfile` task so that the line is originally inserted in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to read the file, get the list of users that are in `HideUsers=` (if there are any), and then append a specified user to that list. This new list of users can be written out to the file. We can also perform some of these tasks conditionally as well.

The below example seems to get the job done:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: set user details
    set_fact:
       new_user: frodo
       existing_users: []

  - name: get the already hidden list of users
    shell:
     cmd: 'grep "HideUsers=" sddm.conf | cut -d= -f2'
    register: hidden_users

  - name: set list of existing users
    set_fact:
      existing_users: "{{ hidden_users.stdout.split(',') }}"
    when: hidden_users.stdout_lines | length > 0

  - name: create final list of users that should be hidden
    set_fact:
      users_to_add: "{{ existing_users + [ new_user ] }}"
    when: new_user not in existing_users

  - name: add users to hide
    lineinfile:
      path: sddm.conf
      regexp: "^HideUsers="
      line: "HideUsers={{ users_to_add | join(',') }}"
    when: new_user not in existing_users
```

Although it seems that it might be easier to maintain a list of users to hide as a variable (in inventory for example), so we have a single point of configuring this file.